# Ubuntu pixelated screen on suspend

Tags: 20.04, graphics, suspend, amd-graphics, amd-ryzen

I have a ThinkPad x13, 1st Gen laptop with Ubuntu 20.04 and Windows 10 dual boot. It's been about a week and when I suspend the machine, I am getting pixelated screen  trying to wake it up.

Below is the description of my machine:

```
Distribution: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Kernel Release: 5.13.0-27-generic
CPU Model: AMD Ryzen 5 PRO4650U with Radeon Graphics
```

[image]

I tried a bunch of options from google but it didn't seem to work out. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: If you hold the power button down for 5+ seconds to power it off and start the machine up again, does the screen display normally?

Comment: This looks like a hardware problem. Either a bad display, loose video cable, bad Radeon video controller, or shared RAM memory. Does tapping on the display, or the top of the computer, make the problem come and go?

Comment: Go to https://www.memtest86.com/ and download/run their free `memtest` to test your memory. Get at least one complete pass of all the 4/4 tests to confirm good memory. This may take a few hours to complete.

Comment: @heynnema it's not a bad display problem, tapping on display, or the top of computer does nothing.

Comment: @matigo turning off the computer doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: @asdfjkl Tapping on the display/computer was only to test for a flaky video cable. The rest of my previous comment still holds true. Take it to a technician/repair shop. One last test you can try... boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if it works there... it probably won't.

Comment: @heynnema, this problem doesn't appear on windows. So, I don't think that's a hardware issue.

Comment: @asdfjkl Do you know how to boot Ubuntu using nomodeset from the GRUB menu? At the GRUB menu, select Ubuntu, then hit the "e" key to enter edit mode. Find "quiet splash" and change it to "quiet splash nomodeset", then control-x or F10 to continue booting. Tell me what happens.

Comment: @heynnema, on nomodeset, when I suspend my laptop, my screen doesn't wake up i.e. I get dark screen instead of pixelated one.

Comment: @asdfjkl Well that was inconclusive. Did you try booting to a Ubuntu Live USB as per my comment from 2 days ago?

Comment: @heynnema, on live USB, the issue cannot be reproduced i.e. pixelated screen doesn't appear upon waking from suspend.

Comment: @asdfjkl Good. Next test... at the GRUB menu, choose Additional Options, and then choose a kernel older than -27. Retest. Report back. Also show me `dkms status`.

Comment: @heynnema, for the older kernel version (5.11.0-46-generic), the problem doesn't seem to appear.  Here's the o/p of `dkms status` 
```
acpi-call, 1.1.0, 5.10.0-1057-oem, x86_64: installed
acpi-call, 1.1.0, 5.11.0-46-generic, x86_64: installed
acpi-call, 1.1.0, 5.13.0-27-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Comment: @asdfjkl Please see my preliminary answer. If it's helpful, please remember to accept it by clicking on the checkmark icon that appears just to the left of my answer. Thanks!

Comment: @heynnema, how can i update my `Radeon Graphics` driver? There's no option shown in `Software & Updates` and `Software Updater` to update graphics driver. Please help I am a noob ubuntu user. And also, how to reinstall the kernel?

Comment: @asdfjkl I added a link for the Radeon driver in my answer. Try Ubuntu 21.10 first. Then removing the acpi-call dkms software. Then the Radeon driver. Then the kernel.

Comment: @heynnema, why should I try ubuntu 21.10? Doesn't this work on my current version of ubuntu?

Comment: @asdfjkl Try the Ubuntu Live USB 21.10. That way you don't have to make any modifications to your existing system, and you don't have to install it. Trying this will just eliminate a Ubuntu problem with your configuration, or with a corrupt install on your current system. Remember that certain steps must be taken to identify exactly where the problem is with your system. Based on my suggestions, we already have determined that an older kernel works fine. Just follow along with my answer.

Comment: @asdfjkl After booting to a Ubuntu Live USB 21.10, open a terminal and type `uname -r` so we can see exactly what kernel it's using.

Comment: I am facing exactly the same problem as you!  Even the patern, say, left side pixel-ish and right-side is stride-ish.

Comment: Ubuntu bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-hwe-5.13/+bug/1958591

Comment: Almost same Lenovo X13 model in use here and facing exactly the same problem with KDE Neon 5.23. If it helps: - I get this screen also if splash screen is ON during boot. - If screen is switched OFF and ON again (-> power safe)
- Second screen via an external monitor seems to work

Comment: Hi @heynnema, right now I am in a village and don't have stable internet connection. I will update you next week.

Comment: This issue is now fixed for me. I suspect it was some mesa updates from yesterday.

Comment: This issue seems to be resolved in kernel `5.13.0-30-generic`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your configuration...

```
Distribution: Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS
Kernel Release: 5.13.0-27-generic
CPU Model: AMD Ryzen 5 PRO4650U with Radeon Graphics
```

**Note**: Booting to an older `5.11.0-46-generic` kernel and the computer works fine.

**Note**: Booting to a Ubuntu Live 21.10 USB and the computer works fine.

dkms status

```
acpi-call, 1.1.0, 5.10.0-1057-oem, x86_64: installed 
acpi-call, 1.1.0, 5.11.0-46-generic, x86_64: installed 
acpi-call, 1.1.0, 5.13.0-27-generic, x86_64: installed
```

To further narrow down where the actual problem is...

- Try booting to a Ubuntu Live 21.10 USB

  - You can boot to a Ubuntu Live 21.10 USB just to test, without installing it
  - In the `terminal`, type `uname -r` to see what kernel it's using
- Let's check if you have a current BIOS (ThinkPad x13, 1st Gen)

  - In `terminal`, type `sudo dmidecode -s bios-version`. One of the following links pertains to your exact model #...

    - https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x13-type-20t2-20t3/downloads/driver-list/component?name=BIOS%2FUEFI
    - https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x13-type-20uf-20ug/downloads/driver-list/component?name=BIOS%2FUEFI
- Try removing the `acpi-call` kernel extension

  - `sudo dkms remove acpi-call/1.1.0 -k 5.13.0-27-generic`
  - `sudo update-initramfs -u -k 5.13.0-27-generic`
  - reboot to the -27 kernel
- Try updating the `Radeon Graphics` driver

  - https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-21-40-1
  - https://www.amd.com/en/support/kb/release-notes/rn-amdgpu-unified-linux-21-40-2
- Try reinstalling an `OEM` kernel

  - Check the Lenovo web site downloads for your model

**Update #1:**

This issue seems to be resolved in kernel 5.13.0-30-generic.

Comment: This issue seems to be resolved in kernel `5.13.0-30-generic`